# Is resourceNames comma separated in Google people getBatchGet?

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-people-api

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet

> resourceNames  string
>
> The resource names of the people to provide information about.
>
> To get information about the authenticated user, specify people/me. To
>   get information about a google account, specify people/account_id. To
>   get information about a contact, specify the resource name that
>   identifies the contact as returned by people.connections.list. You can
>   include up to 50 resource names in one request.

It specifies `resourceNames` to be string, but does not mention whether it's comma separated or not, while `personFields` is comma separated.

In official clients, it's type is also `string`, so I am guessing it is comma separated?

I am using Node by the way: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/people/v1.ts#L2399

Its type is strictly `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use the several `resourceNames`, please use the following query parameter.

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet?requestMask.includeField=emailAddresses,names&resourceNames=people/me&resourceNames=people/123456789
```

When you use this, please encode as follows.

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet?requestMask.includeField=emailAddresses%2Cnames&resourceNames=people%2Fme&resourceNames=people%2F123456789
```

#### Reference

- [Method: people.getBatchGet](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet)
- [apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.getBatchGet)

  - You can also confirm the endpoint here, when the several `resourceNames` are used.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Added :

When you want to use it at googleapis, please use it as 1 dimensional array.

```
const people = google.people({version: 'v1', auth});
people.people.getBatchGet({
    resourceNames: ['people/me', 'people/123456789',,,],
    personFields: 'emailAddresses,names',
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using node client. I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice that you are using Node.js. Can I ask you about your current script and the version of googleapis?

Comment: No worries. My bad for not specifying it at first. I am using the latest version.

Comment: Thanks. I will run it when I finish my code, but for now it throws a type error because it only accepts string. ( I am using typescript )

Comment: @Joon I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Although I'm not sure about your script from your question, I added a sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried and it throws a static typecheck error. I haven't ran the code yet. My code isn't ready to test yet. I will let you know if it runs ok despite of typecheck error.

Comment: @Joon Thank you for replying. As a report, now I could confirm that in my environment, this script worked at the latest version of googleapis. I hope this also works at your environment.

Comment: Oh really. Thank you. I guess then, their typescript type is wrongly specified. I filed a bug on repo: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1266 Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. You are too kind :)

Comment: @Joon Thank you, too!